# Cannot Plot in Excel Following CSV Data Import (all values = 0)

Tags: excel, csv

I have recently upgraded from Office 2010 to 365. I imported a CSV data file into excel to create a plot from the data. The data appears correctly, but when I insert  a chart to plot the imported data, all values appear to be zero. It seems that in some instances the data is displayed in the cell, but cannot be plotted.

My initial reaction was that the format of the imported data may have spaces or other characters forcing the cells to contain text rather than numbers, but this isn't the case (see below for a sample). Changing the cell format after import does nothing.

I can perform operations on the problem data using a formula within excel (e.g. '=A1 + B1') and everything works. If you add two of the problem cells together, you get the correct result in the correct format and the new cell contains a value that can be plotted.

If I import the same delimited data file into Excel 2010, then everything works fine, including plots.

**What has changed between the two versions that could cause this unusual behaviour?**

See below in the screenshot, I have plotted a series of decimal values in Excel (O360) after transposing the original data, and the plot shows all zeroes on the y axis despite the cells containing data. It does not see them as values for plotting, but it does see them as values within formulae - which is very odd.

*Note: In the plot below I manually typed the left most column which forms the x axis*

[image]

This is the format of my imported data row. I see nothing wrong with it:

```
0.312551;0.137288;0.137288;0.283603;0.200974;0.223328;0.200974;0.223328;0.194638;0.240637;0.194637;0.240637;0.0930865;0.0930865;0.047336;0.047336;0.0646357;0.0646357;
```

Comment: Most likely, your values are text. If you select the cell, that black triangle in the upper left will likely return a "number as text" error.  And changing the format does not change whether the value stored will be seen as a number or as text. The addition operator can convert Textual numbers to numbers; but other methods cannot (eg `SUM`; charting).  Something in the manner in which you are importing the data that has resulted in this.  You can convert them to "real" numbers by performing an arithmetic operation;  eg `copy` a cell containing a `1`.  Select the range; `PasteSpecial` multiply.

Comment: How are you importing? You can usually select the formatting in the import wizard. If the cells are formatted as number before the import and you tell the import to treat the data as numbers then you should get numbers in the end. You can also use VBA to run the import and control the format.