# How do I plot csv data imported using Excel's default import wizard?

Tags: excel, csv, graph, import, legacy

I am running into an issue while trying to plot the data I have imported into Excel from a csv file. I have plotted csv files like these in the past using older versions of Microsoft Excel but the newest version of Excel is giving me problems.

First, I imported the data from my csv file by navigating to **Data>From Text/CSV>**, then selecting the csv file, **>Import>Load**. The data *seems* to have imported correctly. But then when I select my data and hit **Insert>Scatter with Smooth Lines**, it doesn't graph correctly:
[Default Wizard's Resulting Graph (Actual Result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Ss4.png).

After enabling the Legacy wizard from **File>Options>Data**, and importing the csv file from **Data>Get Data>Legacy Wizards>From Text (Legacy)**, the data can be plotted like in older versions of Excel: [Legacy Wizard's Resulting Graph (Desired Result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTx6p.png).

Do note that for both of these cases, I selected the same cells and then plotted the data. But in the default wizard, it doesn't work. When I try to select the columns individually, the y-values all turn to 0; similar to [this unanswered query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955259/cannot-plot-in-excel-following-csv-data-import-all-values-0). I tried converting the formats to "Number" instead of "General" but it does not help.

How do I plot csv data that is imported using the latest version of Excel? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is the raw CSV file for reference

```
Time of Export: 2021-03-30 1:10:00,,,,
Start Date / Time: 2021-03-30 12:00:00,,,,
End Date / Time: 2021-03-30 12:30:00,,,,
Sample Rate: 1 minute(s),,,,
,Temperature Probe 1,Temperature Probe 2,Temperature Probe 3,Temperature Probe 4
TimeStamp,TP 1001 temperature (ｰC),TP 1002 temperature (ｰC),TP 1003 temperature (ｰC),TP 1004 temperature (ｰC)
2/2/2021 12:00,23.23676,0,20.62355,21.99797
2/2/2021 12:01,22.48625,0,20.65972,21.84425
2/2/2021 12:02,21.63628,0,20.53313,21.84425
2/2/2021 12:03,20.52409,0,20.3975,21.70863
2/2/2021 12:04,19.23105,0,20.44271,21.6815
2/2/2021 12:05,17.82046,0,20.30708,21.49161
2/2/2021 12:06,16.2019,0,20.23473,21.18417
2/2/2021 12:07,14.29398,0,19.76454,20.99429
2/2/2021 12:08,12.23235,0,19.49327,20.55122
2/2/2021 12:09,9.998917,0,18.95074,19.89113
2/2/2021 12:10,7.964409,0,18.30874,19.42094
2/2/2021 12:11,5.749062,0,17.60344,18.68851
2/2/2021 12:12,3.316696,0,17.27792,18.12789
2/2/2021 12:13,1.11039,0,16.52741,17.63961
2/2/2021 12:14,-1.493782,0,15.50564,16.91623
2/2/2021 12:15,-3.645836,0,14.65567,16.22902
2/2/2021 12:16,-5.598961,0,13.49826,15.11683
2/2/2021 12:17,-7.714844,0,12.57595,14.48387
2/2/2021 12:18,-9.866898,0,11.40046,13.3988
2/2/2021 12:19,-11.69344,0,11.21058,12.9919
2/2/2021 12:20,-14.09867,0,10.22497,12.12384
2/2/2021 12:21,-16.55816,0,9.519676,11.59035
2/2/2021 12:22,-18.64692,0,8.588326,10.8308
2/2/2021 12:23,-20.63622,0,7.693146,10.17072
2/2/2021 12:24,-22.58029,0,7.204865,9.809029
2/2/2021 12:25,-25.03979,0,6.192131,8.515984
2/2/2021 12:26,-27.01099,0,4.817711,7.575592
2/2/2021 12:27,-29.67846,0,4.085289,6.445313
2/2/2021 12:28,-31.88477,0,3.072556,5.712891
2/2/2021 12:29,-33.65704,0,2.765121,5.387367
2/2/2021 12:30,-35.41124,0,2.48481,4.636864
---------------------------------------------,,,,
```

Comment: Most likely your data is being interpreted as TEXT, possibly due to the blank lines at the top of the column. (Changing the cell format does not change the data type).  Use **Import>Transform** and properly type the columns in Power Query before loading to the worksheet. If that doesn't work, create a sample that reproduces the problem, and paste it as text into your question.

Comment: Oh, I did not realize that changing the format using the Windows ribbon doesn't alter the data type. I tried hitting **Transform** now and changing the data type to "Decimal Number" but the info that is present previously and the headers disappear. I suppose the quick fix would be to delete all the preceding data but I would think there's another way to do it perhaps. Thanks for the feedback! I will keep fiddling around meanwhile.

Comment: If you can live with the results, one easy method would be to delete the first five rows; then promote the sixth row (now the first row) to Header.  Proper data typing can then occur.

Comment: There are ways of combining the fifth and sixth rows to make a two line header; and possibly combining the first six rows so as to retain the identification data. Then you'd wind up, in Excel with a multiline header

Comment: I think your quick-fix method of deleting the first five rows (and then reinsert them afterwards) seems like the best method so far. 

I'm not sure how to combine rows though. Is that part of the **Transform** function?

Comment: I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although removing the first five rows, and promoting the sixth to be the header, is a quick fix; if you want to retain the topmost information, you will need to combine those six rows, and then promote them.

- Transpose the table
- Combine the first six columns, using `<linefeed>` as the separator
- Transpose the table
- Promote the first row to headers
- Type it (can be done automatically by the UI)
- Be sure to (in Excel), enable **word wrap** and size the rows/columns correctly.

*The disadvantage of this method is that there will be a lot of information in the first row, instead of it being split into separate rows*

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\sampledata.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=5, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(Source),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Transposed Table",
        {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6"},
        Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Transposed Table1" = Table.Transpose(#"Merged Columns"),

    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table1", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{
        {"Time of Export: 2021-03-30 1:10:00#(lf)Start Date / Time: 2021-03-30 12:00:00#(lf)End Date / Time: 2021-03-30 12:30:00#(lf)Sample Rate: 1 minute(s)#(lf)#(lf)TimeStamp", type datetime}, 
        {"#(lf)#(lf)#(lf)#(lf)Temperature Probe 1#(lf)TP 1001 temperature (ï½°C)", type number}, 
        {"#(lf)#(lf)#(lf)#(lf)Temperature Probe 2#(lf)TP 1002 temperature (ï½°C)", Int64.Type},
         {"#(lf)#(lf)#(lf)#(lf)Temperature Probe 3#(lf)TP 1003 temperature (ï½°C)", type number}, 
         {"#(lf)#(lf)#(lf)#(lf)Temperature Probe 4#(lf)TP 1004 temperature (ï½°C)", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

**Results from your data**

*The values to be plotted are now numeric*

[image]

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Power Query Editor but it did present an option via **View>Advance Editor** to paste the code you provided and it did work! I tried to replicate your steps but was stuck on what you meant by "Combine the first six columns, using <linefeed> as the separator" and "Type it (can be done automatically by the UI)" . I found the **Transpose** command under **Transform** and "Promote the first row to headers" step but but couldn't do the other steps.

Comment: @MezJ After you **Transpose**, the first six rows would be the first six columns.  You could then select those columns; **Merge** columns has an option for the separator which would be the linefeed.  Then you **Transpose** back and that merged column would become the first row.